# Mongodb Stitch unsupport $geoNear in collection.aggregate(). Alternative $geoWithin does not have includeLocs

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

[$geoNear matching nearest array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44280713/geonear-matching-nearest-array) in this question suggested to use $geoNear and its option "includeLocs". However, this aggregate is unsupported in MongoDb Stitch function. You can read in documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/actions/collection.aggregate/#unsupported-aggregation-stages
In MongoDb Stitch I can easily query with geospatial, using $geoWithin. But I can't separate my return model. Is there any alternative "includeLocs" or how can I filter $geoWithin result?

My model is:

```
[
  {
    "locations": [
      {
        "address": "bla bla bla",
        "city": "Avila Beach",
        "coordinates": [
          -120.73605,
          35.17998
        ],
        "country": "Usa",
        "prods": [
          {
            "brand": "kumcho",
            "cagtegory": "tire",
            "id": "1_kumcho"
          },
          {
            "brand": "micheline",
            "cagtegory": "tire",
            "id": "1_micheline"
          },
          {
            "brand": "setrr",
            "cagtegory": "rim",
            "id": "1_setrr"
          }
        ],
        "state": "5 Cities"
      },
      {
        "address": "data data data",
        "city": "Arvin",
        "coordinates": [
            -118.84151,
            35.21617
        ],
        "country": "Usa",
        "prods": [
        ],
        "state": "Bakersfield",
      }
    ],
    "name": "My Car",
    "admin": "John"
  }
]
```

According to this model, When I query like below.

```
.find({"locations.coordinates": {$geoWithin: {$centerSphere: [[-120.55361687164304, 35.22037830812648], 15/3963.2]}}},{"locations.coordinates":1})
.toArray()
```

Aggregate alternative.

```
const pipeline = [
    {$match: {"locations.coordinates": {$geoWithin: {$centerSphere: [[-120.55361687164304, 35.22037830812648], 15/3963.2]}}}}
  ];

const cursor = coll.aggregate(pipeline);
```

the result is:

```
[
  {
    "locations": [
      {
        "coordinates": [
          {
            "$numberDouble": "-120.73605"
          },
          {
            "$numberDouble": "35.17998"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "coordinates": [
          {
            "$numberDouble": "-118.84151"
          },
          {
            "$numberDouble": "35.21617"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But I want specific array object of the document with root, which match with the searched coordinates.

For example, I need something like that.

Search values:
 
`lon = -120.55361687164304`
 
`lat = 35.22037830812648`
 
`kmml = 3963.2`  (this is miles)
 
`distance = 15`

According to search values above, the matched model coordinates is:

`"coordinates": [-120.73605, 35.17998]`

So I want result something like that:

```
[
  {
    "locations": [
      {
        "address": "bla bla bla",
        "city": "Avila Beach",
        "coordinates": [
          -120.73605,
          35.17998
        ],
        "country": "Usa",
        "prods": [
          {
            "brand": "kumcho",
            "cagtegory": "tire",
            "id": "1_kumcho"
          },
          {
            "brand": "micheline",
            "cagtegory": "tire",
            "id": "1_micheline"
          },
          {
            "brand": "setrr",
            "cagtegory": "rim",
            "id": "1_setrr"
          }
        ],
        "state": "5 Cities"
      }
    ],
    "name": "My Car",
    "admin": "John"
  }
]
```

is it possible return specific fields in mongodb document?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

geoNear Deprecated Since Version 4.0. You can try to use $near $geometry;
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/

```
 //Mile-Km to meters 
  if (kmml == 3963.2){
    distance = distance * 1609.344;
  }  else{
    distance = distance * 1000;
  }

    return coll
        .find({"location":{
              $near: {
                $geometry: {
                    type : "Point",
                    coordinates : [ lon, lat ]
              },
              $maxDistance: distance
            }
        }
        }).toArray();
```

Comment: geoNear is depr, but $geoNear is not, and there is curretnly no other way of doing location queries in aggregation pipeline